# How to refactor 'lock' to 'async/await'?

Tags: c#, async-await, thread-synchronization

We have an old library written in C# targeting framework 2.0. Recently we are going to use it in a modern .net core project and intend to use `async/await`. However, the old library has a lot of `lock` blocks.

We plan to add new `async` methods to implement the same logic.

For example,

the old code

```
void GetOrder()
{
    // ...
    lock(_lock)
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

expected result

```
async Task AsyncGetOrder()
{
    // ...
    await DoSomethingWithLock()
}
```

Please give me some advices about how to translate `lock` into `async/await`.

Comment: Async/Await is not an alternative to lock.

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim()`

Comment: Are you asking for a way to provide thread safety in an async method?

Comment: Are you going to rewrite the old library, or your plan is to use it as is?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias @Llama I'm trying to implement the same logic. I heard `async` and `lock` should not work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SemaphoreSlim](https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/), but if there's a lot of it, the [AsyncLock library](https://github.com/neosmart/AsyncLock) will probably make the conversion much easier (and cleaner).

Just go with the AsyncLock library and relax.

Comment: That library looks a little overbaked

Comment: What do you mean by overbaked and what would be the downsides? Performance needs also need to be taken into account, and both solutions would need to be compared for performance before making a decision -- because he'll be using it a lot.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few general approaches:

## #1 Refactor away from the need for locks at all

Look around for how to write [lock-free C#](https://www.google.com/search?q=lock+free+c%23). Sometimes it involved judicious use of [the `Interlocked` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-6.0). Other times it involves a shift in mindset toward immutable state (ask a functional programmer). There are many cases when doing this has boosted parallel performance significantly.

And of course lockless threadsafe code can be executed either synchronously or asynchronously.

## #2 Refactor away from the need for a reentrant lock, then go async with something that doesn't allow reentrance

This is basically what people are recommending when they recommend `SemaphoreSlim`, the `AsyncEx` NuGet package, or similar.

Stephen Cleary has written about the wisdom behind going this route. He also gives some examples of how to do it:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html

## #3 Find an async drop-in replacement for `Monitor.Lock`/`lock`

Basically what you need is something that gives all three of these at the same time:

- Asynchronicity
- Reentrance
- Mutual exclusion

`Monitor.Lock`/`lock` give you the second and third things. So you want something that gives you the first one also without sacrificing the other two.

This is a little trickier than it might seem. At first glance there are several NuGet packages which appear to do this. But the only *correct* one that I know of is this NuGet package (which I wrote):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReentrantAsyncLock/

Here it is in action:

```cs
var asyncLock = new ReentrantAsyncLock();
var raceCondition = 0;
// You can acquire the lock asynchronously
await using (await asyncLock.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // The lock is reentrant
            await using (await asyncLock.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                // The lock provides mutual exclusion
                raceCondition++;
            }
        }),
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await using (await asyncLock.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                raceCondition++;
            }
        })
    );
}
Assert.Equal(2, raceCondition);
```

This is certainly not the first attempt at doing this. But like I said it's the only *correct* attempt that I've seen so far. Some other implementations will deadlock trying to re-enter the lock in one of the
`Task.Run` calls. Others will not actually provide mutual exclusion and the
`raceCondition` variable will sometimes equal 1 instead of 2:

- [Stephen Cleary's POC](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/v4/Source/Unit%20Tests/AdvancedExamples/RecursiveAsyncLockExample.cs) does not provide mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLKyCX
- [NeoSmart.AsyncLock](https://github.com/neosmart/AsyncLock) does not provide reentrance with mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CkK674
- [Flettu](https://github.com/mysteryjeans/Flettu/) sometimes does not provide reentrance, sometimes throws a semaphore count exception, or otherwise does not provide mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o0c7j7
- [CellWars.Threading.AsyncLock](https://github.com/jasonkuo41/CellWars.Threading.AsyncLock) does not provide mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tz38lN

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It explains the problem (and essentially why it is not addressed by .Net itself) and provides solutions. A lazy referral to a dubious NuGet shouldn't be the marked answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to take into account is that async methods can call non-async methods, but it's not trivial for non-async methods to call async methods and wait for them to finish.

This means that every method that has a `lock` inside of it will probably need to be called only by async methods. You *can* do blocking waits for async methods but then there's no point to refactoring and you have to be very careful to avoid deadlocks.

You also need to be aware that in some project types there's an importance to the identity of the executing thread. For example in WPF there are some things that only the UI thread is allowed to do, and if you launch a `Task` that runs such code  from a thread in the thread-pool, you're likely to experience exceptions.

Having said that, if you want to refactor a method that waits on a lock into an async method that asynchronously waits for a lock/semaphore, you should use `SemaphoreSlim` and `await` the `WaitAsync` call. This way the async method will yield control when the SemaphoreSlim is blocking execution, and resume execution at some point later.